# Java The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to read out a file on a seperate thread and after that I want to move the file to a new directory but the compiler keeps telling me that I can't move the file because it is used by another process. I have checked it multiple times and my readers are closed and I used the `join()` function to wait until the `readThread` has finished what could this be?

```
public class CallLogReader extends Thread {
    private Path path;
    private LinkedList<CallLog> callLogs;

    public CallLogReader(Path path){
        setPath(path);
        callLogs = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public Path getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(Path path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public LinkedList<CallLog> getCallLogs() {
        return callLogs;
    }



    @Override
    public void run(){
        FileReader reader = null;
        BufferedReader buffReader = null;

        try{
            reader = new FileReader(path.toFile());
            buffReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

            String currentLine = buffReader.readLine();
            while(currentLine != null){
                String[] dataBlocks = currentLine.split(";");
                if(!dataBlocks[7].equals("IGNORE")){
                    callLogs.add(new CallLog(Integer.parseInt(dataBlocks[0]) ,dataBlocks[1], ConvertStringToDate(dataBlocks[2], dataBlocks[3]), dataBlocks[4], dataBlocks[5], Integer.parseInt(dataBlocks[6]), dataBlocks[7]));
                }
                currentLine = buffReader.readLine();

            }

        }

        catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        finally{
            try{
                if(buffReader != null){
                    buffReader.close();
                }

                if(reader != null){
                    reader.close();
                }

            }

            catch(IOException ex){
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

     private LocalDateTime ConvertStringToDate(String dateString,String timeString){

        String dateTimeString = dateString + " " + timeString;
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        return LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString,formatter);

    }

    public void moveFile(){
        Path newPath = Paths.get(path.getParent().getParent().toString() + "\\processed\\" + path.getFileName());
        try{
            Files.move(path,newPath,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }

        catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


     public static void main(String[] args) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Path path_1 = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\11601037\\Desktop\\resources\\in\\testdata1.csv");
        CallLogReader reader_1 = new CallLogReader(path_1);
        reader_1.run();

        try{
            reader_1.join();
        }

        catch(InterruptedException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());;
        }

        reader_1.moveFile();
        System.out.println(path_1.getParent().getParent().toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use `System.out.println(ex.getMessage());`, in `catch` use `ex.printStackTrace();`. You get useful information that way.

Comment: This happens to me because I use Google Backup&Synch and occasionally the backup process has an exclusive lock on the file.

Comment: Apparantely my file was open in the background thats stupid of me